# selecting an element by a tag name and class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, tampermonkey

I am trying to capture `a` tags inside a header with known class name.

inspect element:

```
<h3 class="c-card__title">
                    <a href="https://www.springer.com/book/9783030873233" data-track="click" data-track-action="clicked article" data-track-label="article-0">SARS-CoV-2 Spike Protein Convergent Evolution
                    </a>
                </h3>
```

my code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("c-card__title").getElementsByTagName('a');
var vals = [];
for(var i=0;typeof(elements[i])!='undefined';vals.push(elements[i++].getAttribute('href')));
     for (var j = 0;typeof(vals[j])!='undefined'; ++j) {
     window.open(vals[j]);
```

I run it in the browser console but it gives me the following error:

```
VM1065:4 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at <anonymous>:4:66
```

Comment: I read this same question earlier today. I remember because I commented on a couple of things, for instance the semicolon at the end for `for(var i=0;typeof(elements[i])!='undefined';vals.push(elements[i++].getAttribute('href')));`. What happened to the other question?

Comment: @Jákup, i removed the question because the problem was just because i missed changing `getattribute(val)` to `getattribute('href')`. the semicolon at the end of that statement is correct , the code worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `getElementsByTagName` method after `getElementsByClassName`, you should use:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".c-card__title > a");
```

Take a look to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: is there a deeper explanation for this?

Comment: I gave you the link to the documentation but in short:
it will select every element with the class `.c-card__title` who has an `a` as child

Comment: @mohamed `getElementsByXxxName()` return a NodeList. You need to iterate over it to use it with other methods to search.

Comment: But this method simplifies that, because `querySelectorAll()` will do the looping for you.